# WPF Expander still shows Validation Error adorner when shrunk

Tags: wpf, validation, expander, adorner

I've got a style for a `TextBox` to show a validation error message as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
       <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
               <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                       Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                       Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
           </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
       <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate>
                   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <Border BorderBrush="{Binding Path=ErrorContent, 
                               Converter={StaticResource ValidationErrorToBrushConverter}}" BorderThickness="2">
                           <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                       </Border>
                       <Image Name="image1" Height="14" Width="14" Stretch="Fill" Margin="1,1,1,1" 
                              Source="{Binding Path=ErrorContent, 
                              Converter={StaticResource ValidationErrorToImageSourceConverter}}" 
                              ToolTip="{Binding Path=ErrorContent}"/>
                   </StackPanel>
               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>
```

The `TextBox` lives in an `Expander`. When I open the Expander, the `TextBox` allows for input, but will fail validation if the input is `NullorEmpty`, or contains special characters.

My problem is that when I trigger a validation error, the `TextBox` lights up in red and shows an icon with the message as a tooltip. All good so far. BUT when i close the `Expander` without passing validation, the red outline and icon with tooltip are still there! Even with the `Expander` shrunk down! Just floating there... This is not good behavior.

Any ideas on how to get the Validation stuff to hide along with all the other controls in the `Expander`? Also, the Style for validation is declared in the resources of the UserControl, not in the `Expander` itself.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471451/wpf-error-template-red-box-still-visible-on-collapse-of-an-expander/1471733#1471733) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321327/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-red-rectangle-when-my-wpf-binding-validation-has-failed-a/321987#321987) for potential solutions. Either of these two will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up simply clearing the TextBox upon closing the Expander. That way, the validation error goes away and the box is clear and ready for another input when the Expander is opened back up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I fixed it by putting an AdornerDecorator as the first child object of the expander.  The AdornerDecorator is collapsed when the Expander is collapsed, so the Adorners should all disappear too.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this same problem by setting the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` property to null when the TextBox is hidden

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```